# what are the best approach to convert the existing backboneJS app into angularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js

I am trying to convert existing backbonejs application into angularjs. What is the best approach to convert backbone app into angular app. How should I divide and conquer the codes without breaking the app

Comment: This is ***way*** too broad to address in one answer here.  These frameworks are so different in their approach and methods that you can't really expect to reproduce the behavior from one in the other.  Angular is very data driven, so it's very unlikely that you'll be able to avoid rewriting large chunks of the UI to adapt to how the data is presented; it may even be necessary to rewrite or adapt your API calls.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with @Claies that because of the major differences between the two you can't convert the one step by step to the other. However, I do **think** that you can build an angular app using a backbone app as a reference, and that you can use some of the code - mostly the business logic from one app in the other.

I've worked with both backbone and angular in the past, but never tried a conversion, so take my thoughts with a (large) pinch of salt.

Let's see what similar between angular and backbone structure:

1. Views - Backbone has views that can be switched using a router.
   Angular has a views that are controller and template combination
   controlled by a router.
2. Components - Backbone views are composed of sub views, with their
   own model and functionality, rendered by a view or a higher level
   sub view. Angular has directives that a view can compose and each
   directive can contain other sub-directives.
3. Business Logic - Backbone business logic resides in the
   view/model/helper objects. In angular services are responsible for
   the business logic.
4. Models and collections- Backbone has a distinct models and
   collections with a sort of binding and event functionality. Angular
   doesn't have official models. A model can be as small as a variable
   or as large as a tree. Angular models should be handled by a
   service.

So, after this basic review, this is what I would do - mostly view by view I  think:

1. Refactor my backbone app by removing all business logic from views
   and models, and moving them into helper objects.
2. Turn helpers into angular services.
3. Convert models and collections into objects and arrays. Wrap them in
   an angular services - The service will have methods to get and
   update the models. If you need to listen to a model, you can use
   $watch, ng-model & ng-change, or $broadcast an event when you the
   change the model in the service.
4. Turn views into angular views - ie combination of controller and
   template.
5. Turn sub views into directives - passing data from views to
   directives can be done using attributes, services, and events.
6. Templates - both use html templates with bindings, so as long as
   your preserving the models object and array structure you can
   basically convert handlebars to angular pretty easily. After you
   have the model viewed, add event handlers (ng-click and friends),
   and model bindings (ng-model).